# Transform OneHot-encoded data from array to sequence of numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I was trying to use OneHot to encode a column of different categories and save the encoding in a dictionary, since I want to use these exact encodings on a second column with the same categories but in different order. In the dictionary, the valuepairs are saved as

```
{'name1': array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]), 'name2': array([0., 1., 0., 0., 0.]), ...}
```

and this form can't be used for e.g. applying

```
StandardScalar.fit.transform()
```

to them. Is there a way to change these values to suit the "classical" form of OneHotEncoding below?

```
{'name1': 0 0 1 0 0 , 'name2': 0 1 0 0 0 , ...}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is the value type of the second dict ?

Comment: They are in the encoding arrays as well, I think, but the last time I encoded categories like this it replaced everything with these sequences and not with an "array[(..)]". It seems to me like that shouldn't make such a difference, but Python doesn't seem to be able to process this encoding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

conver them do DataFrame `df` which could be also converted as classified one hot array `y`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
a={'name1': np.array([0., 0., 1., 0., 0.]), 'name2': np.array([0., 1., 0., 0., 0.])}
df=pd.DataFrame(a)
y=np.array(df)
```

`df` content is:

```
   name1  name2
0    0.0    0.0
1    0.0    1.0
2    1.0    0.0
3    0.0    0.0
4    0.0    0.0
```

`y` content is:

```
array([[0., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       [0., 0.],
       [0., 0.]])
```

so, you can use either of them

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try this!